# Quick code advice for beginner

Tags: c++, c, pic

I am a beginner and I want to know whats wrong with this code. I want to count the number of times the push button is being pushed in portA. Then show this values using the LEDS in portC. Thanks

Comment: When you ask what's wrong, you should explain what you think is wrong, or how it's not working as you'd expect, so we know what the actual question is you're asking. "I want to know whats wrong" is not a question. You clearly know that PORTC isn't displaying the output you want, so you should state that in your text. :-)

Comment: In 8-bit microcontrollers, using 16-bit int is not recommended and using double is strongly discouraged except when needed. You should use 8-bit char or unsigned char instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need braces around a multi-statement block, if you want to use it as the body of an `if` (or `for` or whatever) statement:

```
else if (PORTA.RA2==1) {
    count = count+1;
    PORTC = count;
}
```

otherwise only the first statement is conditional; so your code executes `PORTC = count;` every time, whatever the result of the `if` tests.

I like to put braces around all such blocks, even there's only a single statement, so I can't forget to add them if I add more statements later.

Also, `main` must return `int` not `void`, and you should take more care formatting your code to match its logical structure.

UPDATE: Also, you never initialise `count`, so it has an arbitrary floating-point value. You want a small integer type, since it's only supposed to take integer values from 0 to 16, and you need to initialise it:

```
char count = 0;
```

Comment: Constantly writing to PORTC shouldn't be a problem, but good catch.

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting TRISA to 1 that means the only input on that port is RA0, but you are trying to use RA2.  Be sure to clear the ANSELA0 bit.  Make sure you set the config bits properly or else your code might not run.

To avoid getting downvoted in the future:

- Choose an informative question title.
- Properly indent your code.
- Say the exact PIC you are using and what board it is on.
- Say what development environment and compiler you are using.
- Provide pictures of your setup so we can check your wiring.
- Most importantly, tell us exactly how you are testing the code, what the expected result is, and what you are actually observing.

My company offers more advice here:  http://www.pololu.com/support

Comment: Also adding the `embedded` tag would reach a wider audience. :-)